# while-loop in python as long as regex matches

Tags: python, regex, while-loop

Ok, I'm aware that it's probably not the best way to edit a string with regex expressions in loops. Just for the sake of interest: How would I have to build a loop, that executes a regex pattern as long as it matches, run in a loop and stop when it doesn't hit anymore? Im doing this in python.

```
match = re.search(r'pattern, repl, str)
while match (is True, == True?):
   sub = re.sub(r'pattern, repl, str)
else:
   Do something else
```

Comment: `re.sub` normally performs the substitution on all non-overlapping matches it finds (although you can limit it by passing a `count` arg), so it is rather unusual to put it in a loop like that, although i guess it makes sense if the result of substitution creates more substrings which match the pattern. However, as nnnmmm points out, you aren't updating `match` inside the loop, so it will either never run, or it will be an infinite loop.

Comment: The goal is to delete line-endings from within p-tags in html. So I search anything from <p> to \n, delete \n and repeat the regex. It works for my purposes when I just repeat the same regex-line again and again. But there should be a loop-solution, too, I think.

Comment: @Pjoern if you want to _correctly_ handle html, use a html parser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`match is not None`, since `match` returns `None` in case of no match, according to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html). But you're not updating `match` in the loop. Did you mean something like:

```
match = re.search(pattern, repl, str)
while match is not None:
    str = re.sub(pattern, repl, str)
    match = re.search(pattern, str)
```

(Note that `search` takes no `repl` argument)

Comment: Yup, this works. Of course, you have to put re.search in the loop.