# Substitute variable amount of numbers by it's sum

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I need to find a way to substitute n numbers in square brackets, only if these brackets are next to each other, by the sum of these numbers in square brackets; e.g.

> A[5][3]B[1.5]C[2.3][-1.3][5]

becomes:

> A[8]B[1.5]C[6]

The closest regex (for matching these brackets in the first place) I've come to is the following one:

```
r'(\[[^\[\]]*\]){2,}'
```

But, with this regex I only match the last occurence (in the previous example: [3] and [5]).

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Possible dupliacte of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48321616/while-loop-in-python-as-long-as-regex-matches)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
import re
s = "A[5][3]B[1.5]C[2.3][-1.3][5]"
rx = re.compile(r"(?:\[-?\d*\.?\d+]){2,}")
print( rx.sub(lambda m: "[{:g}]".format(sum([float(n) for n in m.group()[1:-1].split('][')])), s) )
# => A[8]B[1.5]C[6]
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/LxBt2n).

Actually, you may even try this code with your regex, but note that `[^][]` matches any char but `]` and `[` while `-?\d*\.?\d+` matches an optional `-`, 0+ digits, an optional `.` and then 1+ digits, thus matching negative or positive float and int numbers.

Here, `(?:\[-?\d*\.?\d+]){2,}` matches two or more repetitions of `[<NUMBER>]`s and the lambda expression in the replacement gets rid of the first and last `[` and `]` and splits with `][` to get the list of numbers that are cast to float and then summed. `{:g}` in the `str.format` prints an int if it is an int-like number, or keeps the float values as is.